# fullcalendar@4.0.0alpha.2 associate new event with event source

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar

Fullcalendar keeps a newly created event in cache memory although it explicitly states it won't, if an `Event Source` object is attached to it.

**[From recent release docs:](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/release-notes#events)**

> addEvent: The stick parameter has been removed in favor of a source parameter. When this source is fetched going forward, the dynamic event will be removed. Not specifying a source is equivalent to setting stick to true. **So, by default, events will stick**!

**[Fullcalendar Example of usage:](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/Calendar-addEvent)**

`calendar.addEvent( event [, source ] )`

> 'source' represents the Event Source you want to associate this event with. It can be a string Event Source ID or an Event Source Object. When the source is refetched, it will clear the the dynamically added event from the internal cache before fetching. This parameter is optional.

Therefore, when attaching a source, the newly added event should be associated with that source, and inherit properties? which it doesn't at the moment...

**my code:**

*calendar element*

```
this.calendar = new Calendar(this.calendarEl, {
  // options... 
  eventSources: [
    {
      id: 'internal',
      color: '#ff4202',
      events: (fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) => {
        // Get events in updated weekly range.
        this.eventService.getEvents(fetchInfo.start.valueOf(), fetchInfo.end.valueOf(), moment().utcOffset())
          .subscribe((events: Array<Event>) => successCallback(events),
            error => failureCallback(error));
        },
    }
  ],
}
```

*Add event*

```
this.eventService.createEvent(data)
   .subscribe(response => {
      this.calendar.addEvent(response['event'], ['internal']); // <-- What I am requested to do
   }
```

Cliking the newly created event to fetch its EventAPI data reveals:

`source: null`

While clicking a prefetched event using the `events` function from `CalendarOptions` reveals

`source: EventSourceApi` (the source object)

I cannot find where I'm getting it wrong. If it is reassured as a bug, I will forward it then.

Thank you for any help

Comment: by writing `['internal']` like that you're specifying an array, not a simple string. I'd guess that fullCalendar maybe doesn't understand it. Try just `'internal'` without the `[` and `]`. (P.S. the square brackets in the documentation are, I think, just to indicate that "source" is an optional parameter - that's quite a common convention in code documentation. I don't know if that's what confused you.)

Comment: @ADyson `this.calendar.addEvent(response['event'], 'internal');` without the array brackets returns an error and does not render the event: `Cannot read property 'allDayDefault' of undefined`.

Comment: replacing `['internal']` with `[this.calendar.getEventSourceById('internal')]` as state the docs is another option - does not work either

Comment: the second error might be because the event data isn't populated. Have you checked that? Or it could just be a bug because you're using an alpha version of the plugin.

Comment: P.S. `[this.calendar.getEventSourceById('internal')]` would have to be `this.calendar.getEventSourceById('internal')` (again without the square brackets) if you want to try it that way.

Comment: @ADyson Yeah I tried both methods in both forms. I believe it's safe to announce it is a bug. I'll forward it then. Thank you! =)